# ¿Como convertir la respuesta de una API en formato JSON para poder guardarla en un archivo .json?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Muy buenas a todos,
estoy haciendo una petición a una API, que me devuelve un objeto de tipo 'byte'. 
El tema esta en que no se como hacer para pasar de ese tipo de objeto a un objeto json para poder manipularlo después con PANDAS.

```
import http.client
import json
from pprint import pprint as pp
import pandas as pd

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", 
             f"https://api.sportradar.us/soccer/{key_type}/v4/en/competitions.{formato}?api_key={API_KEY}")

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
data = data.decode('utf-8')
```

La petición me devuelve esto:

> '{\n    "generated_at": "2022-08-18T21:16:17+00:00",\n
> "competitions": [\n        {\n            "id": "sr:competition:1",\n
> "name": "Euro Cup",\n            "gender": "men",\n
> "category": {\n                "id": "sr:category:4",\n
> "name": "International"\n            }\n        },\n        {\n
> "id": "sr:competition:7",\n            "name": "UEFA Champions
> League",\n            "gender": "men",\n            "category": {\n
> "id": "sr:category:393",\n                "name": "International
> Clubs"\n            }\n        },\n        {\n            "id":
> "sr:competition:8",\n            "name": "LaLiga",\n
> "gender": "men",\n            "category": {\n                "id":
> "sr:category:32",\n                "name": "Spain",\n
> "country_code": "ESP"\n            }\n        },\n        {\n
> "id": "sr:competition:9",\n            "name": "Pro League 1B",\n
> "gender": "men",\n            "category": {\n                "id":
> "sr:category:33",\n                "name": "Belgium",\n
> "country_code": "BEL"\n            }\n        },\n        {\n
> "id": "sr:competition:11",\n            "name": "WC Qualification,
> UEFA",\n            "parent_id": "sr:competition:24660",\n
> "gender": "men",\n            "category": {\n                "id":
> "sr:category:4",\n                "name": "International"\n
> }\n        },\n        {\n            "id": "sr:competition:13",\n
> "name": "WC Qualification, CAF",\n            "parent_id":
> "sr:competition:24660",\n            "gender": "men",\n
> "category": {\n                "id": "sr:category:4",\n
> "name": "International"\n            }\n        },\n        {\n
> "id": "sr:competition:14",\n

No sé exactamente como hacer para obtener un objeto json válido.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: y por qué no usas el módulo `json` que estas importando?? `json_obj = json.loads(data)`

Comment: Pues tienes razón, era bastante más sencillo de lo que estaba haciendo para resolverlo. Muchas gracias por la respuesta